# php split each value of an array into 2 with a delimiter

Tags: php

I have a php array with each value in array having a `space` delimiter like

```
a[1]="1 32"
a[2]="2 33"
a[3]="3 67"
...
```

I want to divide this array into 2 arrays using the delimiter `space`. Result should be something like:

```
a[1]="1"
a[2]="2"
a[3]="3"
...
b[1]="32"
b[2]="33"
b[3]="67"
...
```

What should be the optimal way to go about this?

Comment: You may consider using this: http://www.php.net/split and have it store first value at array a[i], and second in b[i]... Consider (i) to be your position in the array in case you insert at random times. (I was just advised that this is out of commission so you may not want to use this)

Comment: @LJ-C `split` is deprecated, it should not be used anymore. `This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.`

Comment: Or maybe [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: @user689: I would say `preg_split()` is overkill for something simple as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your array, use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split each value with space as the delimiter, and push them to separate arrays:

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();

foreach ($array as $value) {
    list($a, $b) = explode(' ', $value);
    $arr1[] = $a;
    $arr2[] = $b;
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/82916)

Answer (score 1):

My take with [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.array-walk.php):

```
<?php

$input = [
    "1 32",
    "2 33",
    "3 67"
];

$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];

array_walk($input, function ($item) use (&$array1, &$array2) {
        $temp = explode(' ', $item);
        $array1[] = $temp[0];
        $array2[] = $temp[1];
    }
);

print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
```

Note: The syntax assumes PHP 5.4. [Demo](https://eval.in/82936).

Answer (score -1):

You may use `explode` http://www.php.net/explode

Eg. `explode(" ", $a[1]);`

Comment: He wants elements in two different arrays a[] and b[] you are putting them in one array.

Comment: I was only trying to show a basic use of the explode function.